# Internet Explorer 11 - Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11

I'm getting this error in IE 11, on all other common browsers it works fine.

I use this code which makes use of 'includes':

```
const keys = Object.keys(this.service.content);

            if (keys.includes(splitUrl[splitUrl.length - 1])) {
                this.router.navigateByUrl(`/mysite/${splitUrl[splitUrl.length - 1]}/1`);
            }
```

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 6):

I was Face same Problem with **Angular 7.0+** and **IE11**

I got solution by adding one line to my `polyfill.ts` file.

```
import 'core-js/es7/array';
```

I get this solution from this article [Internet Explorer 11 and Angular 2+](https://medium.com/agilix/internet-explorer-11-and-angular-2-50beda010aae)

**NB:** If you want to avoid this kind of situation for **IE** browser then you should read this article Thanks to [Maarten Merken](https://medium.com/@M3rken).

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is looking for ReactJS solution -

Used `import 'core-js/es6/string';` at the start of `index.js` to solve my problem.

I'm also using `import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';` to support running React in IE11.

> react-app-polyfill
>
> This package includes polyfills for various
>   browsers. It includes minimum requirements and commonly used language
>   features used by Create React App projects.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-app-polyfill/README.md

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `angular/cli`, open up `polyfills.ts` file and uncomment the required polyfill.

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
// import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
// import 'core-js/es6/object';
// import 'core-js/es6/function';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
// import 'core-js/es6/number';
// import 'core-js/es6/math';
// import 'core-js/es6/string';
// import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
// import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
// import 'core-js/es6/map';
// import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
// import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

You might also want to include other polyfills required by `IE11`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use either a polyfill for `Array.prototype.includes` or old good `Array.prototype.indexOf`

```
 if (keys.indexOf(splitUrl[splitUrl.length - 1]) !== -1) {
   this.router.navigateByUrl(`/mysite/${splitUrl[splitUrl.length - 1]}/1`);
 }
```

Comment: hmmm indexof doesn't give me the same results strangely... but it's definitely helping me getting in the right direction

Comment: @bobdolan what do you mean by "same results"? could you please provide an example?

Comment: What I'm doing in my code is I compare an object (type: string) with the splitted URL.
If the splitted URL contains the string it redirects the user to another section.

Comment: Thanks, indexOf worked like a charm. It's a pity in a way though that for the support of relict browsers one needs to spend time and effort...

Comment: @YuriKiriachek usual advice here is to support IE first, all other browsers will just work ;)